# Ionic list not loading on device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a demo app for practice, using Ionic. It works fine on the web browser but is not working properly on the device.

HomePage HTML code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
        Test App
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item (click) = newPage(post) *ngFor = "let post of posts">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{post?.multimedia.src}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{post?.display_title}}</h2>
      <p>{{post?.byline}}</p>
   </button>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts code:

```
export class HomePage {
posts: Array<object>;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
  this.http.get('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/all.json?api-key=a96736504fda41f58b3af1ec5876d3b9')
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
    this.posts = data.results;
    console.log(this.posts);
  });
}

newPage(post) {
  this.navCtrl.push(Pg, {
    post: post
  });
 }
}
```

I ran it on the device using the command:

```
ionic run android --device
```

The app opens on the device, but only the header is loading. The list does not appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: what happens if you replace `<img src="{{post?.multimedia.src}}">` by `<img [src]="post?.multimedia.src">`. Can you inspect the console to see what the error is? I think it may be related to the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

Comment: That didn't work. I debugged using Chrome Tools, and got the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - cordova_plugins.js"

Answer (score 0):

Try and initialize your posts array with an empty array like this

```
posts: Array<any> = [];
```